# WinRT - ImageButton for transparent PNGs

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, winrt-xaml-toolkit

I'm using XAML Toolkit ImageButton control to be able to create normal and pressed states for a button. Code is:

```
<toolkit:ImageButton NormalStateImageSource="ms-appx:///Assets/1_off.png"
                         PressedStateImageSource="ms-appx:///Assets/1_on.png"
                         Width="500"
                         Height="200">
</toolkit:ImageButton>
```

Issue I'm facing is, say I have a shape which isn't rectangle or square. For example I have PNGs for star and arrow object. Is there a way to set their boundary corresponding to shape? If not, please advice the best approach to handle such scenarios.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two options I tried

1. When clicking using mouse or touch - you'd check the last position of the pointer before click and see if the image in your button has a non-transparent pixel at that position.

   - **Pros:**

     - It's simpler than option 2.
     - You get most precise information
   - **Cons:**

     - You can't tell if a button got clicked with mouse, touch, pen, keyboard or by narrator using automation, so you could end up filtering out keyboard clicks just because the mouse cursor is a bit off. You could possibly use some heuristics like how long ago was the pointer move or pointer down event before the click event, but it's a bit hacky and might be unreliable.
2. Generate a vector path for your image and put it in the button template as a `Path` element with `Fill="Transparent"`, then mark any other non-transparent or hit testable template elements (buttons, borders with Background="Transparent", etc.) as `IsHitTestVisible="false"`.

   - **Pros:**

     - Doesn't break any input methods
     - Can be quite precise
     - For some shapes like a circle - the `Path.Data` could be quite simple or you could even use something like an `Ellipse` element instead
   - **Cons:**

     - You need to generate the path somehow
     - A complex path might adversely affect performance

A better solution overall in most cases is to leave the hit-testable area rectangular. The reason is - an arbitrary shape is a finicky and unreliable hit test target so it makes clicking your button more difficult. Using the default rectangular border or at most - an ellipse shape is a lot simpler and more usable.